# Slow Down Playback of a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am trying to gradually slow down a movie clip using Actionscript 3. My current code plays the movie clip and then abruptly stops and ticks ahead a few frames. A much rougher look than I want.

```
var t:Timer=new Timer(2000,1);
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,slowDown);
t.start();

function slowDown(e:TimerEvent):void {

    if (currentFrame==totalFrames) {
        gotoAndStop(1);

    } else {

       gotoAndStop(currentFrame+1);
    }
}
```

Is the Timer class at least the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to employ the power of a Tweening Engine - there are quite a few of them out there, but my favourite is [Greensock TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/).

The following code will tween the playhead of a MovieClip gradually slowing down (easing) as it nears the end of playback:

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

TweenMax.to(myMovieClip, 2, { frame: myMovieClip.totalFrames, ease: Expo.easeOut });
```

Comment: That's the winning answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a simple ease to a known location you can use this on enterframe:

```
speed = 0.2; // Somewhere between 0 and 1
x = (targetX - x) * speed;
```

You can change targetX when ever you like, and it will just ease to the value. You can do this for any property.